# Inno Setup Download Plugin is failing with "Download failed: Cannot create file"

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, inno-download-plugin

I have been attempting to make an installer for an application where the required files are on a server. I am using Inno Setup with Inno Download Plugin. During the download portion of the setup I'm getting the following error:

> Download failed: Cannot create file %tempFileLocation%\%filename%.zip".

I'm not sure if the error is an ability not to connect to the server, permission issue within the temp directory, or what the problem is. If I put the URL used directly into a browser I can download the file with no problems.

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
    idpAddFile('%URL', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\%directory%\%filename%.zip'));

    idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);
end;
```

Everything with the '%' signs are actual hard coded values. Any help either resolving this issue or pointing me to a better resource than what I've found on my own would be appreciated.

Comment: Quotes are in the code just somehow I missed them in the example. The %directory% is the actual name of the directory within the {tmp} that this file will need to be stored in for example 'bin'. The directory is listed within the [Dirs] section of the script to be created. I'm not allowed to give too much because of proprietary reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to download the file to a directory that does not exist.

The `[Dirs]` section is processes only after the user confirms the installation. While the `InitializeWizard` is run even before the wizard shows.

As I assume you need the file downloaded before the installation starts, you have to create the directory in the code using [`CreateDir` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createdir), not using the `[Dirs]` section, like:

```pascal
CreateDir(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\%directory%'));
```